# Selenium with Chrome profile : if other Chrome tabs are open it doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

If I use selenium to open chromium using my chrome profile, the script works only if there are no other chrome tabs open otherwise it just open a chromium tab but it doesn't go to the URL.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Paul\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 5')
wd = wd.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
wd.get("URL")
```

The error is:

```
wd = wd.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
Opening in existing browser session.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Paul\Desktop\folder\file.py", line 16, in <module>    wd = wd.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00628893+48451]
        (No symbol) [0x005BB8A1]
        (No symbol) [0x004C5058]
        (No symbol) [0x004E3211]
        (No symbol) [0x004E0019]
        (No symbol) [0x00510798]
        (No symbol) [0x0051047C]
        (No symbol) [0x0050A0B6]
        (No symbol) [0x004E7E08]
        (No symbol) [0x004E8F2D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00888E3A+2540266]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008C8959+2801161]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008C295C+2776588]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x006B2280+612144]
        (No symbol) [0x005C4F6C]
        (No symbol) [0x005C11D8]
        (No symbol) [0x005C12BB]
        (No symbol) [0x005B4857]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76DC00C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FE7B4E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FE7B1E+238]
```

I am new to programming and any help would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get your 'usr-data-dir' in Chrome, use the link chrome://version, where you can see "Profile Path," which consists of a path to your profile. Remove the last directory, save the rest of the link in  'usr-data-dir," and paste the last directory name in 'profile-directory'.

To run Selenium in your existing Chrome profile, you need to close all the Chrome browsers that are running in the background  (use the task manager to end those running tasks). Then start executing your script; it should work fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

def driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
    options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
    driver_obj = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver_obj.maximize_window()
    return driver_obj

wd = driver()
print("rendering link")
wd.get("https://www.google.com")
print("Link rendered Successfully")
sleep(20)
wd.close()
```

If you don't want to close the currently running browser and need to execute your script, you need to use the Chrome driver as your service or executable path and also have the latest Chrome version installed on your system.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import os


def driver():
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install())
    os.chmod(service.path, 755)
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-using')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    return driver

wd = driver()
print("rendering link")
wd.get("https://www.google.com")
print("Link rendered Successfully")
sleep(20)
wd.close()
```

Run this command to install the required package:

```
pip install selenium webdriver-manager
```

Comment: Thank you for you beautiful answer. I would like to run Selenium in a Chrome profile without having to close my Chrome running browsers. I tried to add `options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")` and `options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')`  in your last code but it still doesn't work when other Chrome browsers are open.